# How to Solve the Following Coupled System of Equations

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations

I have obtained the following coupled system of equations as a solution to a couple of a second order ODE with variable coefficients. I have used the method of variation of parameters and got the following solution, however, I can't decouple them easily. I need to get an explicit solution for each dependent variable.

$$ Y_1(x) = f_1(x) + g_1(x)\int h_1(x)\cdot Y_2(x) dx$$
$$ Y_2(x) = f_2(x) + g_2(x)\int h_2(x)\cdot Y_1(x) dx$$

Comment: Variation of parameters shouldn't normally give you something like this.

Comment: @ Robert Israel  I have a couple of two dependent second order ODEs, like that $$ Y''(x) + a(x) Y'(x) + b(x) Y(x) = c(x) Z(x)$$  and $$ Z''(x) + d(x) Z'(x) + e(x) Z(x) = f(x) Y(x)$$ So, I procced to solve every equation alone for the corresponding dependent variable considering the second dependent variable as unknown function. I got the homogenous solution and the particular solution in terms of the second dependent variable. As for the first integral equation, $$f_1(x)$$ represents the homogenous solution and $$ g_1(x)\int h_1(x)\cdot Y_2(x) dx $$ is theparticular solution.

Comment: Better might be to substitute $Z(x) = c(x)^{-1} (Y''(x) + a(x) Y'(z) + b(x) Y(x))$ into the  second equation, getting a single fourth-order homogeneous linear DE for $Y$.  Of course there's no guarantee you'll be able to solve it explicitly.

Comment: @  Robert Israel, I have already used this technique and proceeded to get the solution by using power series technique, however, the obtained solution can't satisfy the boundary conditions for my problem $ y(0) = 1 & y(infinity) = 0